# How to sanitize request object in the @restcontroller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, checkmarx, secure-coding

I'm doing a static code analysis using checkmarx, which gave me medium vulnerabilities for @RequestBody.

Will place a sample code below, could someone help me fixing this issue.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Slf4j
@Validated
public class Myclass {

@Autowired
SplitClass split;

@PostMapping(path = "/something", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public int splitter(@RequestBody SplitRequestVO **splitReq**) {
    int response = 0;
    try {
        int value = split.methodName(splitReq);
        if(value == 1) {
            response = 1;
        }else {
            response = 0;
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Excpetion in the MY Class controller" +e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}
```

}
Every time it is showing error with this util class. please check whats wrong in this class.

```
@Slf4j
public class FileUtil {

    private FileUtil() {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("FileUtil.class");
    }


    public static void createFileFromBytes(String fileName, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            log.error("Exception in creating file from bytes : "+exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void deleteFile(String fileName) {
        log.info("Entry into deleteFile method.");
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (file.exists()) {
                Files.delete(file.toPath());
                if (log.isDebugEnabled())
                    log.debug("file deleted:" + fileName);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in deleting the file : "+e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("Exit from deleteFile method ");
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        log.info("Entry into getBytesFromFile method");
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            long length = file.length();
            if (length > 2147483647L) {
                log.error("File Too large:" + file.getName());
            }
            bytes = new byte[(int) length];
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0)
                offset += numRead;
            if (offset < bytes.length)
                throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in getBytesFromFile : "+e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("Exit from getBytesFromFile method ");
        return bytes;
    }

    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        return getBytesFromFile(file);
    }

}
```

Here im facing the vulnerability issue to fix in the block letters. Appreciated foy help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact vulnerability they listed?

Comment: Method getBytesFromFile at line 45 someother util class. gets user input for the bytes element. This element’s value is eventually used to define the application’s ‘sleep’ period, in getBytesFromFile at line 45 . This may enable a DoS by Sleep attack. Update above @Daniel

Comment: @Rishi. you should check the sleep duration and validate the authenticity of data. Once data is validated, you can also enforce the sleep interval, how frequently requests are being fired.

Comment: @Daniel I have some vulnerabilties for : 1. This may cause a Path Traversal vulnerability. and also 2. This constitutes an Unchecked Input for Loop Condition.